# INSERT FROM SELECT with Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to insert values from table program_day_exercise into table training_exercise. So i wrote this query:

```
@Query("""
    INSERT INTO training_exercise
    SELECT 0, :trainingId, exercise_id, num, measure_weight, measure_reps, measure_time, measure_distance
    FROM program_day_exercise
    WHERE program_day_id = :programDayId
""")
fun fillTrainingWithProgramExercises(trainingId: Long, programDayId: Long)
```

It compiles, but there is an runtime error about UNIQUE constraint:

```
02-23 13:31:12.618 11881-12003/com.dmitrysimakov.kilogram E/SQLiteLog: (1555) abort at 34 in [INSERT INTO training_exercise
        SELECT 0, ?, exercise_id, num, measure_weight, measure_reps, measure_time, measure_distance
        FROM program_day_exercise
        WHERE program_day_id 
02-23 13:31:12.618 11881-12003/com.dmitrysimakov.kilogram E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
Process: com.dmitrysimakov.kilogram, PID: 11881
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: training_exercise._id
```

Then I wrote this query in other way:

```
@Query("""
    INSERT INTO training_exercise (training_id, exercise_id, num, measure_weight, measure_reps, measure_time, measure_distance)
    SELECT :trainingId, exercise_id, num, measure_weight, measure_reps, measure_time, measure_distance
    FROM program_day_exercise
    WHERE program_day_id = :programDayId
""")
fun fillTrainingWithProgramExercises(trainingId: Long, programDayId: Long)
```

It works fine. But SQLite plugin cannot resolve parameters in parentheses.

[image: problem]

I added @Suppress("AndroidUnresolvedRoomSqlReference") before the method, but I’m wondering why the plugin considers this a mistake.

---

My entities

```
@Entity(tableName = "training_exercise",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
                entity = Training::class,
                parentColumns = ["_id"],
                childColumns = ["training_id"],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(
                entity = Exercise::class,
                parentColumns = ["_id"],
                childColumns = ["exercise_id"],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
])
data class TrainingExercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) override val _id: Long = 0,
    val training_id: Long,
    val exercise_id: Long,
    val num: Byte,
    @Embedded(prefix = "measure_") val measures: ExerciseMeasures = ExerciseMeasures()
)

@Entity(tableName = "program_day_exercise",
    foreignKeys = [
ForeignKey(
        entity = ProgramDay::class,
        parentColumns = ["_id"],
        childColumns = ["program_day_id"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
ForeignKey(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        parentColumns = ["_id"],
        childColumns = ["exercise_id"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
])
data class ProgramDayExercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) override val _id: Long = 0,
    val program_day_id: Long,
    val exercise_id: Long,
    val num: Byte,
    val strategy: String? = null,
    @Embedded(prefix = "measure_") val measures: ExerciseMeasures = ExerciseMeasures()
)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `@Query` annotation does not support `INSERT` query because it can potentially conflict your `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you're selecting the the first row and inserting it back into the database. If the `id` field is unique or a primary key this will fail, as obviously you can't insert a duplicate record.

Looking at the error message we see `training_exercise._id`. Are you sure that the attribute is `training_id` and not `id` or `_id`?

Comment: _id attribute in training exercise is autoincremented. Therefore, I specifically missed it so the SQLite would generate the next value.

Comment: In your second query you're trying to INSERT into the training_id attribute. If it's actually called _id you need to change it to that.

Comment: I want the SQLite to generate an _id. Therefore, I passed 0 in the first query and missed it in the second query.